Spurious zero printed in seaborn barplot while plotting pandas dataframe
The following is the minimal code. A spurious zero is printed between second and third bars that I am unable to get rid of in the plot. Please help me fix the code. A minimal working example is below:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {
    'Temp': [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
    'Measurement': ['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'std', 'std', 'std', 'std', 'std', 'min', 'min', 'min', 'min', 'min', 'max', 'max', 'max', 'max', 'max'],
    'Value': [-0.03, -0.05, -0.07, -0.09, -0.09, 0.24, 0.44, 0.69, 1.11, 1.45, -2.36, -4.56, -5.86, -11.68, -14.68, 1.30, 3.50, 5.26, 9.28, 11.14]
}

df_melted = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df_melted)

barplot = sns.barplot(x='Temp', y='Value', hue='Measurement', data=df_melted, palette='viridis')

for p in barplot.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2.
    if height >= 0:
        barplot.text(x, height + 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)
    else:
        barplot.text(x, height - 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)

plt.ylim([-25,25])   
plt.show()

Verions: Python 3.12.4, matplotlib 3.9.1 and Seaborn 0.13.2
PS: Edited to include maplotlib version.

with seaborn  0.12.2 and matplotlib   3.7.1 I do not get this insanity and your code seems to run as it should.

The additional 0.0 is from the legend patches (in fact four 0.0s on top of each other). You can iterate over the bar containers instead:
for c in barplot.containers:
    for p in c:
        height = p.get_height()
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2.
        if height >= 0:
            barplot.text(x, height + 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)
        else:
            barplot.text(x, height - 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)


An easier way to label the bars is, howver, using bar_label instead of re-inventing the wheel.
for c in barplot.containers:
    barplot.bar_label(c, fmt='%.1f', rotation=90, padding=2)


Thank you! Was modifying examples on internet to adapt to my needs but, could not find a solution. I tried disabling ticks but of course that failed too. Now I can see why.

For some reason, the last four elements of barplot.patches are rectangles with height = 0 and width = 0, so you could add an if statement when you add the text to the plot:
for p in barplot.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    width = p.get_width()
    if height != 0 and width != 0:
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2.
        if height >= 0:
            barplot.text(x, height + 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)
        else:
            barplot.text(x, height - 0.1, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=10, color='black', rotation=90)


Pardon me, how would the output be any different in such cases?

With the if-statement, the text indicating the height of the four bars with height 0 and width 0 are not included in the plot. These bars were the cause of the spurious 0's, thus not plotting them results in the desired output without the spurious 0's - but @Stef has a better solution iterating over barplot.containers rather than barplot.patches is a better solution.
